# Do I need to specify each link color state?

Tags: css

I'm using the following pseudo classes:

```
a.recentposttitle:link,a.recentposttitle:visited {color:#000;}
a.recentposttitle:hover {color:#56A49F;}
a.recentposttitle:active {color:#000;}
```

Do I need to be that explicit or is there a more compressed way to get the same result?

Comment: for stable result you must do that

Comment: Explicit use will be good. So that you can target specific areas.@4thspace

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no shorthand. But your selectors can be:

```
a {}
```

to select all `links`, or:

```
.recentposttitle {}
```

to get all `.recentposttitle` elements (we know that they are links already).

---

And another thing, `:link` is not needed really, you can write:

```
a {}
a:visited {}
a:hover {}
a:active {}
```

When you write `a {}`, you will set the declaration for all possible situations, so:

```
a {}
```

Is identical to:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {}
```

- And remember, the order of `pseudo classes` are importent:

  - :**l**ink
  - :**v**isited
  - :**h**over
  - :**a**ctive
- Or simply remember **L**o**V**e **HA**te.

Comment: `a` and `a:link` are not exactly identical. `a:link` selects all anchor elements which is actually a link `<a href="…">`, whereas `a` also selects anchor elements without the href attribute.

Comment: I'm not completely following your example.  You've removed the class .recentposttitle.  So your code has a larger target...right?

Comment: @4thSpace Yes, `a {}` will select all links, and so, it has a larger target.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shorthand selector in CSS for the pseudo-classes of anchors/links. So what you have is pretty well as terse as you can get.

[W3 Link Training](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/links)

```
a:link{ Declarations }
a:visited{ Declarations }
...
a:hover{ Declarations }
a:active{ Declarations }
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to find the reference I've previously read to confirm this, but AFAIK, the `:link` pseudo-selector is only necessary if you are using old-style page anchors (`<a name="..."></a>`), so you should be able to safely eliminate that. Since your `:active` and `:visited` rules are the same, you could probably cut down what you've shown to this:

```
a.recentposttitle:active, a.recentposttitle:visited {color:#000;}
a.recentposttitle:hover {color:#56A49F;}
```

But you're not really saving that many bytes, so hard to say if it's worth it.

Comment: The order of `pseudo` classes are important, so `:active` must be after `:hover`. Therefore, the links never get black when you click them. Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/X5kTE/).

Comment: @NOX Odd - the jsFiddle you linked to works for me (clicking the link causes the color to be black when not hovering). I may need to create a working demo to see what works with real links. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Click and `hold` the mouse. The link must be black at that time ;)

Comment: @NOX Ah, there's the problem. Good eye.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress it by using CSS Frameworks like `LESS` or `SASS`.

Like from your example,

**The CSS:**

```
a.recentposttitle:link,a.recentposttitle:visited {color:#000;}
a.recentposttitle:hover {color:#56A49F;}
a.recentposttitle:active {color:#000;}
```

For example if you use **SASS** you can compress it to..

```
a.recentposttitle {
  color: #000;
  &:link{ color: #000; }
  &:hover { color: #56A49F; }
  &:visited { color: #000; }
  &:active{ color: #000; }
}
```

You can also use `Emmet`, previously known as `Zen coding` for maximum code compressions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: SASS and LESS are CSS preprocessors, which allow writing clean CSS in a programming construct instead of static rules. - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LESS_%28stylesheet_language%29#Comparison - @4thSpace